# Is there any way to detect PDF/email in NetSuite Advanced PDFs?

Tags: templates, pdf, netsuite

Is there any way to detect if an advanced PDF is being used as a PDF or an email in NetSuite?

I would like to format accordingly.

Something like:

```
<#if current_format=="email">Show some html stuff.<#else>PDF version</#if>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no 'state' information available in to the template generator that I can think of.  All it knows is the record context you(or NetSuite) gave it.

The output of the advanced template is XML regardless of its final destination. It's converted to PDF or HTMl output after having been generated.  (See: nlapiCreateTemplateRenderer() and nlapiXMLToPDF() documentation in NetSuite for more info.)

If you need to format the content differently, the simplest method is probably to use 2 separate forms.